# как получить данные формы в Webflux Spring

Tags: java, spring

На фронте есть форма:

```
 <form  method="post" action="searchshops">
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" name="searchId" id="searchId">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="searchId">
                            по ID
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="searchTitle" id="searchTitle">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="searchTitle">
                            по Названию
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="searchAddress" id="searchAddress">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="searchAddress">
                            по Адресу
                        </label>
                    </div>

                <div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchValue" placeholder="Поиск"
                               aria-label="Поиск по ID">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary " type="submit" id="button-addon2">
                                Найти
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input hidden="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}">
            </form>
```

Не могу никак на контролере получить данные с чекбоксов.

```
public Mono<String> searchShops(Boolean searchId,
                                     String searchValue)
                                    {
```

и так:

```
 public Mono<String> searchShops(@ModelAttribute("searchId") Boolean searchId,
                                     String searchValue)
                                    {
```

и так:

```
 public Mono<String> searchShops(@RequestParam("searchId") Boolean searchId,
                                     String searchValue)
                                    {
```

И вместо Boolean пробовал String и никак. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данные с формы приходят скорее всего в multipart/form-data посмотрите в сторону https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html